# Flink reduce on a keyed stream without window

Tags: apache-flink

I read the source code , reduce will forword every result to downstream.

---

I want reduce a stream by key without window,

```
    stream.keyBy(key)
          .reduce((a, b) -> {
                //reduce
                return a+b;
          });
```

if reduce on window, flink will forword element to downstream when watermark arrived, so how flink determine reduce finish without window.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/

> **Reduce**
>   KeyedStream → DataStream
>
> A "rolling" reduce on a keyed data stream. Combines the current
>   element with the **last reduced value** and emits the new value.
>
> **Window Reduce**
>   WindowedStream → DataStream
>
> Applies a functional reduce function to the **window** and returns the
>   reduced value.

The key difference is that:

- When `reduce` is done in a Window, the function combines the current value with the window one.
- When `reduce` is done in a KeyedStream, the function combines the current value with the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

With stream processing, in general there isn't the idea that computations "finish". They just keep going indefinitely. The non-windowed reduce just keeps on reducing for as long as you leave the job running.

Answer (score 0):

If you do reduce without window, Flink will emit a partial aggregated record **after each element the reduce operator encountered**. It's very dangerous for the performance, and in most cases it's not what you want.

Here is a quick Scala example to show the problem:

```scala
package org.example

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, createTypeInformation}

object TestReduce {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val stream = env.fromCollection(Seq(
      ("k1", 1),
      ("k1", 1),
      ("k1", 1),
      ("k1", 1),
      ("k1", 1),
      ("k1", 1))
    )

    stream
      .keyBy(_._1)
      .reduce((p, q) => (p._1, p._2 + q._2))
      .print()

    env.execute("test reduce")
  }
}
```

Running the code above will output:

```
1> (k1,1)
1> (k1,2)
1> (k1,3)
1> (k1,4)
1> (k1,5)
1> (k1,6)
```